# Calculating differentials between cell velocities

Tags: calculus, computational-mathematics, fluid-dynamics

If I have a 2D cell-based fluid simulator, which uses velocities and pressure, how can I find the change in pressure between the neighboring cells for a cell? I might be missing something big here, but I need to find the partial differential of pressure over with respect to the partial change in X, so the cells on the left and right.

In the shown picture, the cell with pressure of 2 is shown. This cell is at, lets assume, (2,1) given the borders on the bottom. How can I find the partial of pressure with respect to partial X if from the left it decreases by 0 but on the right decreases by 1?

Forgive any simple calculus mistakes which I may of made. Hopefully the answer is much more simple than I think. Thank you!

[image: pic1]

Comment: How are you doing the rest of your spatial derivatives (for velocity etc.)?

Comment: @David Thats what I was looking for! I haven't implemented any spatial derivatives yet, one question is that should I go for dP = Pressure(cell at 2,1) - Pressure(cell at 1,1)? What would the difference be between if I wanted to find the spatial derivative through using the focus cell and the one on the left, versus the one on the right? Thanks a bunch

Comment: will it be a partial derivative or total derivative? because it seems that you are trying to calculate pressure as a function of x only.

Comment: @T.an In this case, the original equation for the vector direction uses the gradient of the pressure scalar field. Since I wanted to break this into x and y directions, each vector is only using the x value. It's a partial derivative from what I assume,
Originally the grad(pressure) = [ partial p / partial x, partial p / partial y], so I only am using partial p / partial x to find the x value

Comment: @Blake correct me if I am wrong. it seems that you are dealing with navier stokes equation and trying to solve that numerically. If so then you have to deal pressure in a different way.

Comment: @T.an I am working with Navier Stokes, just with a limited background knowledge. Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Which way am I supposed to deal with pressure?

Comment: I think you have got into a much bigger project than you anticipated, beyond the scope of a qa site this. I'd recommend you read something about "finite differences" as ways to solve differential equations, and then something specific to solving Navier-Stokes numerically. I don't have good reference suggestions in mind though, sorry.

Comment: @Blake As David says  your problem is some how bigger and you will get it from literature. To deal with pressure term you have to follow "stream function vorticity " approach to be exact. you can google it or find the total solution in any book related to advanced fluid mechanics as it is a generic appraoch to solve navier stokes equation.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm totally aware of the large thing I've gotten myself into, literally everything I'm doing is new for me and its a good opportunity to do so. Thanks for the pointers in the right direction